# Couchbase PHP SDK: How to detect couchbase connection failure?

Tags: php, couchbase

I am using Couchbase PHP Extension to connect to Couchbase and implementing a feature that can detect if Couchbase is not responding and failover to MySQL. However, I can't figure out how to detect if Couchbase is down, I cannot find anything in their documentation for that.

Following is the code I have:

```
$cb = new Couchbase("$host:$port", $admin, $password, $bucket);
if (!$cb) {
    throw Exception('Cannot connect to couchbase!');        
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same question, and solved it this way:

```
$cb = @new Couchbase($host.":".$port,$username,$password,$bucket,$persistent);
if($cb->getResultCode() != COUCHBASE_SUCCESS){ 
    throw Exception('Cannot connect to couchbase!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend counting errors up to a threshold and then consider the connection 'down' and try to rebuild it.

Note that part of the reason it's difficult to determine 'down' is that Couchbase, by design, would rarely completely fail and even when failed nodes do occur, failover is triggered either automatically or manually bringing that connection object back online.  It's different in this regard than connections to other databases.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any API method we can use to determine the healthy node count in the cluster?

Comment: This doc should help you find those API calls http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/getting-node-info.html