# How to handle connection failures in Couchbase?

Tags: php, couchbase

I'm using Couchbase to do short-term caching of RDBS results from PHP 5.4 NTS under IIS 7 using `php_couchbase` and `libcouchbase`. If you put the RDBS select in a callback function the code is pretty nice, but I'm looking for a better understanding of what to do when things fall apart.

SO suggests I look at this questions: [Couchbase PHP SDK: How to detect couchbase connection failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532444/couchbase-php-sdk-how-to-detect-couchbase-connection-failure). Saad's code won't throw an exception, because `$cb` is never false. (I'm not sure what to make of Matt's suggestion of counting errors; I've not been able to make it throw any.)

I'm fine with object instantiation working even when the DB is offline; since the connection could go down at any time, code should check the result of each operation. But `libcouchbase` seems unwilling to let failure be an option.

In the following code (in which I am connecting to a bogus port) it never throws exceptions, just "warnings". (`"Warning: Failed to establish libcouchbase connection to server: Connection failure in H:\www\root\no.php on line 4", "Warning: There is no active connection to couchbase in H:\www\root\no.php on line 9"`).

`Couchbase->add` returns a value, but the returned value can't show the difference between "this key already exists" and "the server room is on fire".

What is the right way to test whether an operation succeeded?  Do I need to be trapping warnings?

```
<?php

try {
  $cb = new Couchbase("localhost:8099", "", ""); // should be port 8091
} catch (CouchbaseException $e) {
    echo "Never fires, even when db down (this is OK...instantiation did work).";
};

if ($cb->add("hello","hello world")) {
  echo "Called if DB up and key does not exist";
} else {
  echo "Called if DB down or key exists";
}

try {
  $foo = $cb->add("hello","hello world");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Never fires, even when db down";
};

try {
  $foo = $cb->add("hello","hello world");
} catch (CouchbaseException $e) {
    echo "Never fires, even when db down";
};

print $cb->get("hello");

?>
```

I also tried [this code from the documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-php-1.1/api-reference-summary-exceptions.html); no exception thrown. Maybe I don't have php exception handling turned on? (Sorry if I'm being an idiot here, I don't write much php code.)

I'm a little frustrated by the party line that since Couchbase is a distributed redundant nosql blah blah blah solution we don't have to think very much about service availability. Code always needs to know when data got thrown on the floor.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Rob

Comment: We definitely think you need to have availability and contingency code in your application to handle connectivity or other errors! It's standard for any data storage to do so. I will spin up something and see the best way to handle loss of connectivity, great question btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to check to be certain, but I believe the problem is related to the fact that the Windows build there is a bit behind.  There was, if I recall correctly, a problem with exception handling in the earlier 1.1.x series.  Building from source may be in order.  I'll see if we can get you an updated build.